# Laravel install package without composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ftp, composer-php, package

I'm just wandering if I can ask this here. I'm trying to install a package called [Laravel Page Speed](https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed/issues/74) from my site that has already been hosted. My question is how can i install this package / any kind of package without composer into my hosted site. Or if i can install this with composer, how can i do this ?

I use Filezilla for ftp.

I've tried using the `cmd`'s `ftp` command but its not working. Anyone have manage to do this ? Any answers will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Could you give a reason why you do not want to use composer?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski thankyou for replying. My problem is idk how to use composer in already hosted application or is it even possible ?

Comment: If you have SSH access in your hosting, you can install and use composer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have ssh access to server and then just run this  :

```
composer require PACKAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is shared hosting. Please setup the project on local machine and then install the required package. After installing just replace the hosted site’s vendor directory with your local vendor directory through any ftp client and it should be installed there too.